# What does Failed building wheel for pynacl mean?

Tags: pip, python-wheel

Sometimes when installing requirements associated with my python project, I get "Failed building wheel for cryptography" or "Failed building wheel for pynacl".

Then I get "Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography"

What is happening here? Is it something to be concerned about? Or is it simply installing the packages via an alternate method?